# Prevent a tabBar moving to the next View Controller onselect

Tags: ios, swift

I have an item on my tabBar which I don't want to actually move to its view controller but instead when that item is clicked something happens (a popup dialog appears over the current view controller).

I currently have the current code:

```
class TabViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // tell our UITabBarController subclass to handle its own delegate methods
        self.delegate = self

    }

    // called whenever a tab button is tapped
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

        if viewController is PostTabViewController {
            ... code here ...

        } 
    }


}
```

The code at ..code here... runs just fine however the PostTabViewController is still shown. How would I go about stopping it?

Comment: what do you mean by still down ?? also what is the issue you want to fix ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan Sorry I thought I was pretty. clear, I don't want the PostTabViewController to be shown I just want the code '... code here ...' to be run and then the 'select' event to be canceled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do your checks in `tabBarController(_, shouldSelect:)`

```
func tabBarController(UITabBarController, shouldSelect: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard viewController is PostTabViewController else {
        return true
    }

    ... code here ...
    return false
}
```

Comment: how can i show the pop from bottom with hidden tab bar item when clicked specific tab bar index and also not open the viewcontroller with tab bar

Comment: The code I posted will prevent it from opening the view controller. Put any other action you want to do at `... code here ...`.